# How to load a webpage fully without scrolling when using puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I have a site that I need to screenshot some parts. I was able to isolate the parts I want by using Xpath and take a screenshot. The problem is, when there are more than 3~4 parts it only renders the element only after it comes to the view port. So the Xpath only picks first 3~4 elements. The current approach is to scroll the page to the bottom using this code

```
async function autoScroll(page){
    await page.evaluate(async () => {
        await new Promise((resolve) => {
            var totalHeight = 0;
            var distance = 100;
            var timer = setInterval(() => {
                var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
                window.scrollBy(0, distance);
                totalHeight += distance;

                if(totalHeight >= scrollHeight - window.innerHeight){
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    resolve();
                }
            }, 100);
        });
    });
}
```

The problem with this is some pages contains more than 300 elements, with means It takes about 30s just to scroll. I cannot speed it up because If I do the elements will load incorrectly.

`waitUntil : networkidle2 / 1` or `waitForNavigaton` does not work because when the page loads it only ask for the resources for the viewport. But when I scroll it asks for the next resource and so on.

Is there a way to load this webpage fully without scrolling/ (scrolling takes too much time as I said)

**Edit :**

File contails the code responsible for event triggering (I think)
https://codepaste.xyz/posts/zEVum8PmvdSO6PEqMdOQ

Comment: Does the data you want is inside the network response? If yes, you can consider intercept the response data by enabling [setRequestInterception](https://pptr.dev/api/puppeteer.page.setrequestinterception)

Comment: When I scroll the network sends and jsonp file with the data I want. the it renders it in to viewport. I need to screenshot the element because the css applies after that (I guess). Even the data is in the response I still need to scroll to get the response. I do have the code responsible for event trigger... It is much longer than the stacks allowed limit